# Postgresql Composite Key with resetting auto_increment

Tags: database, postgresql

I am currently implementing a database structure that has a Composite Key composed of four columns.
e.g.

```
 create table if not exists example (
   id1 varchar(5) not null,
   id2 varchar(1) not null,
   id3 int,
   id4 int,
   ...
   primary key (id1, id2, id3, id4)
 );
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to delegate the key increments to Postgresql instead of managing it programatically. My goal is to do something like such:

```
-----------------------------
  ID1  |  ID2  |  ID3  |  ID4
-----------------------------
  abc      a       1       1
  abc      a       1       2
  abc      a       1       3
  abc      a       2       1   -- ID3 increments here; ID4 resets to 1
  abc      a       2       2   -- ID3 remains 2; ID4 auto increments
  abc      b       1       1   -- ID2 changes; ID3 resets to 1; ID4 resets to 1
```

Thank you in advance for your time and support.